# New relic browser index.html

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, newrelic

I have node express app
I have public folder /public also it add like **app.use(express.static('./public'));** 
and there index.html
so when I running

```
 node server.js
```

it shows me localhost:3000/index.html
How can I put in **index.html**

```
newrelic.getBrowserTimingHeader()
```

to see in localhost:3000/index.html **NREUM** object

Answer (score 0):

New Relic for Node requires that an application be using an HTML templating library to inject the headers.

They have full documentation here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/supported-features/page-load-timing-nodejs

The important bits to look at are the examples. These are from the docs on the example with using Express and Jade:

> The simplest way to insert browser timing headings is to pass the newrelic module into your template, and then call newrelic.getBrowsertimingHeader() from within the template.

**app.js**

```
var newrelic = require('newrelic');
var app = require('express')();
// in express, this lets you call newrelic from within a template
app.locals.newrelic = newrelic;

app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.render('user');
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    != newrelic.getBrowserTimingHeader()
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

The chunk where the `newrelic` module gets set the application locals for use in the template is the important bit: `app.locals.newrelic = newrelic;`.

There's simply no way to run something in a static file the way Express's **static** module works by default. It pretty much streams the text content of the static file directly.

Comment: but if don't want to use render scenario only index.html ?

Comment: @ButuzGOL, New Relic doesn't support that case. The scripts have to be injected into the page somehow, and the only way to do that is by injecting into a template.

Comment: @ButuzGOL it does support it but you will have to do the copy and paste method of adding the newrelic-browser.js file. https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/new-relic-browser/installation-configuration/adding-apps-new-relic-browser#copy-paste-app